# Can Deep Recurrent Networks (Modelling of Sequence / Panel Data) handle feature vectors of different dimensions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, panel-data, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently learning on sequence modeling with the coursera course from deeplearning.ai about
RNN in general as well as the GRU and LSTM. However I am now one week in and still not sure, if these algorithms can model the data we are interested to analyze.

**What we want to analyze**
We have panel data with some waves (i.e., sequences, e.g. from $T_1$ to $T_8$). With some questionnaires assessed at every timestep (e.g. our outcome, let's assume it could be Depression Sumscale measures with the BDI), and some shared predictors between all sequences (e.g., age, gender, daily activiy). This, as far as my understandings goes, could work fine with a `many-to-many architecture` where $T_x = T_y$.

**Open Question**
Can RNNs (either RNN traditional, GRU, or LSTM) handle differences in the input of $x^{<t>}$? E.g. a questionnaire on quality of relationships is assessed at timepoits $x^{<1>}$ and $x^{<2>}$, but was dismissed for all further waves. Or a newly developed questionnaire on fear related to Cov-19 was introduced in $x^{<8>}$? So my question is, can RNN handle such form of input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can. A common approach is to embed each multi dimensional feature separately into one vector, and then continue with these vectors into the main RNN, LSTM network.

Examples for how to reduce multi dimensional input features into one vector:

- Embed each input separately and do average embedding or weighted average embedding.
- Use attention in order to get a learned weighted average of the embedding to get one vector.
- Put the feature into another RNN\LSTM cell, and extract the last layer as the result for the reduced vector.
- Put the features in to a subnet of dense layers and take the final layer as the result for the reduced vector.

As an example, questionnaire on quality, you can make an embedding for $x_1$ and $x_2$ separately, then use average embedding or use one of the above methods, this will give you one vector that will represent the, questionnaire on quality, and then you can pass this vector along with other inputs into main RNN.

Comment: Thanks so much. I hope this will be mentioned in the course in the future, as I think I understand it in general but it is still a little abstract to grasp for me. However this answers my general question if this is even possible. One short follow up question: Lets say quality has 5 items then I would have one vector of size $\vec{x_q}^{<1>} = [5]$ as one input of the tensor $x^{1}$ and another for sequence two $\vec{x_q}^{<2>} = [5]$. And then from sequence $t = 3$ on the vector would be just an empty vector? So $\vec{x_q}^{<3>} = \vec{0}$ same for all consecutive sequences $t = [3;8]$

Comment: @SysRIP definitely, padding with zeros is also very common way to handle variable change input.